# how to address a soapinterface on localhost?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have to consume a webservice with delphi-XE3 to retrieve information from a distant webserver on base of a unique number that I must send with my xml request.

I have the linkadress of the WSDL file that I can import into my project, but I have not a URL for sending my request to.

Instead according to the administrator of the remote webservice I have to address the SOAP interface on localhost and in the WSDL file the defurl is defined as:

<<<http://localhost:8080/.....>>>>>>

So my question is: how to do that ? 
All the examples that I found of consuming a website with Delphi are with an external URL to send the request to, but I found none that retrieves distant information by means of listening to localhost. 
Do I have to install an additional program or where do I find a tutorial to manage this.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

**You know, it is not really a Delphi question, aren't you?**

This question is more of the protocol, IDE or test environment kind.

---

**Anyway:**

If you want to test your application on your local host, you have to have an instance of the server software to provide the service you wish to use. If you don't have it and still want to test locally (and you are totally aware of the answers the server should send), you can fake it by setting up an RPC or (at least) a HTTP server on your computer, but I would not recommend it, since it will only test your application against your expectations instead of a real life scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however I do not want to test any application; I just want to send my requestxml file to the webserver for an answer and according the instructions of the company of the remote webservice I should do that by addressing my soap interface on localhost; but I do not understand how I can retrieve information from the remote webservice by 'listening to a localhost directory'. In the WSDL file they provided me the defURL is indeed a localhost directory with port 8080. I expected an external URL and do not understand what localhost has to do with this.

Comment: @user3147440: Hard to answer, since nobody knows about your setup here. `I have the linkadress of the WSDL file that I can import into my project, but I have not a URL for sending my request to.` - So what is that "linkaddress", if it's not an URL? And what did the guy assigning the task to you answer, when you asked him about the URL you expect?

Comment: thank you for the help; I think I have figured it out; the wsdl donwloadable from an external link gives me the routines for addressing the webservice but the webservice is to be installed locally; so I have to send my soap request to localhost; the webservice on localhost or a computer of the local network will then change like encrypting the message and send it to the remote webservice and give back an anser to the service on localhost; so I have to listen on localhost; it was indeed not a good question but I am completely new to webservices and localhost.